# Tableau: Conditional Formatting Rows based on a data range

Tags: tableau-api

Any help you can provide would be appreciated. I can't find any tableau tutorials that deal with conditional formatting based on dates.  Plenty of formatting based on cell values, but that doesn't help in this case.

I am trying to create a tableau report that shows the change records that are due within the below criteria and color code the rows accordingly.

The next seven days represented by "red"
The next 14 days represented by "yellow"
Greater than 14 days out represented by "green"
Everything else would have a white background

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of your worksheet? Especially for table questions, there are usually various solutions depending on how you set it up. Please make sure you include the whole Tableau window (including shelves, dimension and measures, etc)

Comment: Please describe more about result. Which graph you want to implement ?

Answer (score 0):

Something I did that sounds similar was around due dates:

1. Create a calculated field called "Due Date Traffic Lights" to work out your days amount. The below gives the date difference between the given date field and today:

   ```
   DATEDIFF('day',MAX([Due Date]), MAX(TODAY()))
   ```
2. Create calculated field "if" function called "Due Date Range" to categrorise these results:

   ```
   if [Due Date Traffic Lights] < -7 THEN "GREEN: Over One Week Left"
   ELSEIF [Due Date Traffic Lights] > -7 AND [Due Date Traffic Lights] <0      
   THEN "ORANGE: Due in one Week"
   ELSE "RED: Overdue"
   END
   ```
3. So on your rows you can then drag the "Due Date Range" into your "Color Icon" and set the color for each of the 3.